# Fix a vertex at a known location in SpatialGraphDistribution

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, distributions

I can very quickly generate random geometric graphs with

```
density = 1600; r0 = 0.05; Ngraphs = 100;
n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[density], Ngraphs];

graphs = Table[
    RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[n[[k]], r0]], {k, 1, 
     Ngraphs}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.890343, Null}

but would like to add a vertex at the exact center position `{0.5,0.5}` in each graph, and then connect it to all vertices within range `r0`.

I have used

```
pts = PropertyValue[graphs[[1]], VertexCoordinates]; // AbsoluteTiming
Nearest[pts, {0.5, 0.5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000062, Null}
>
> {0.000145, {{0.507425, 0.491059}}}

but then `EdgeAdd` is quite slow since I have to use `Position` to find the name of the vertex at those coordinates. Is there some efficient way to do this?

My problem has been that this `SpatialGraphDistribution` technique is the fastest way to generate large graphs, but I need to fix vertices at a specific Euclidean separation in order to measure the graph distance/Euclidean distance relation.

Note: Slyvniak's Theorem is related to this idea of conditioning the graph to contain a vertex at a point, though that refers to the Poisson point process specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fourth input form in the `Nearest` documentation:

```
Nearest[pts -> "Index", {0.5, 0.5}]
```

> {989}

It will return the vertex position instead of the coordinate.

Also I recommend you to use `GraphEmbedding` instead of `PropertyValue[graphs[[1]], VertexCoordinates]`:

```
pts1 = PropertyValue[graphs[[1]], VertexCoordinates]; // AbsoluteTiming
pts2 = GraphEmbedding[graphs[[1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000039, Null}
>
> {4.*10^-6, Null}

```
pts1 == pts2
```

> True

Adding edges with new coordinates:

```
edges = Thread[UndirectedEdge["center",
               Nearest[pts -> VertexList[graphs[[1]]], {0.5, 0.5}, {Infinity, r0}]]];

newg = Graph[VertexList[graphs[[1]]], 
  Join[EdgeList[graphs[[1]]], edges], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Append[pts, {0.5, 0.5}]]
```

Comment: If I use `Nearest[Thread[pts -> Range[Length[pts]]], {0.5, 0.5}, {Infinity, r0}]`, can I then add a vertex at {0.5,0.5}?

Comment: Your comments and advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167450/12) would be appreciated.

Comment: halmir, no need to `Thread` the rules for `Nearest`, at least from version 11 onwards: `Nearest[pts -> Range[Length[pts]], {0.5, 0.5}]` works as well and is much faster (internally, the list of rules has to be decomposed and packed again into two seperate arrays). Note also that this is equivalent to `Nearest[pts -> Automatic, {0.5, 0.5}]` and `Nearest[pts -> "Index", {0.5, 0.5}]` (the latter only available in version 11.2.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To complete halmir's answer, I used:

```
  ed[rg_] :=  EuclideanDistance @@@ 
  Map[PropertyValue[{rg,#},VertexCoordinates] &, EdgeList[rg], {2}]

  addvert[gr_, coord_, range_] := Module[{pts, nl, vv, ee},
  pts = GraphEmbedding[gr];
  vv = VertexList@gr;
  nl = Length@vv + 1;
  vv = Join[vv, {nl}];
  ee = Join[
    Thread[nl <-> 
      Nearest[Thread[pts -> Range[Length[pts]]], 
       coord, {Infinity, range}]], EdgeList@gr];
  Graph[vv, ee, VertexCoordinates -> Join[pts, {coord}]]
  ]

density = 5; r0 = 0.7; Ngraphs = 1;
n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[density], Ngraphs];
graphs = Table[
    RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[n[[k]], r0]], {k, 1, 
     Ngraphs}]; // AbsoluteTiming
graphs = Parallelize[
    SetProperty[#, EdgeWeight -> ed[#]] & /@ 
     graphs]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

then run

```
graphs[[1]] = addvert[graphs[[1]], {0.5, 0.5}, r0]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

to simultaneously add a new vertex at `{0.5,0.5}`, and attach it to all those vertices of the graph within a distance of `r0`. The timing is

> {0.000527, Null}

So it is quite fast. The `VertexAdd` and `EdgeAdd` method was difficult to use, since the `VertexCoodinates` get renamed as `Automatic` for some reason.